# Whitebox GAT breaks when opening map document

Tags: whitebox-gat

I really enjoy using Whitebox GAT for spatial analysis, in particular DEM/hydrological modeling- though I'm having a consistent issue trying to open saved maps.

Every time I try to open a wmap file, a blank prompt (titled "message") pops up with an "ok" button.  Either the prompt pops up many times causing Whitebox GAT to break (with me having to use task manager to end task), or it pops up once and I click ok.  In the latter case, after I click ok my layers (raster files) associated with the map don't show up.

I'm not particularly adept at understanding xml log files, but there are messages about "error in MapRenderer" and "java.lang.NullPointerException" in the log files.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to avoid these map renderer/other issues?

I'm running Whitebox GAT on Windows 7 pro.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the troubles you're experiencing. I ask that you 1) close Whitebox GAT, 2) delete all the files in your 'log' directory, 3) relaunch Whitebox, 4) open a map and reproduce the error. Finally, under the Help menu, select Report An Error. You have to include an email address in the report if you're hoping for a response from an error report.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I carried out your recommendations.  Interestingly enough, a couple new map files I saved and opened after doing what you said did not recreate any errors but opening an older map from this morning still caused the issue.  The issue I describe above happened with two map files.  I'm not sure what's helpful, but I suppose considering this a one off error and reporting an error if it happens again is a reasonable course of action.  Thanks again!